# c++ - implement storage writer that partially writes compressed data

Tags: c++, zlib, ofstream

In my code, I have two types of writers: regular writer, class `Writer` and compressing writer, class `ZlibWriter`. I need a way to combine both writers.
Please have a look at the code below. sorry that it is a bit too long. I tried posting just the very relevant.

```
typedef std::vector<int> int_vector;

class Writer
{
public:
    void open(string path);
    void close();

    void write(string v);
    void write(bool v);
    void write(int v);
    void write(int_vector v);

private:
      std::ofstream m_fstream; ///< file output stream
};


class ZlibWriter
{
public:
    void open();
    void close();

    void write(int v);
    void write(int_vector v);

private:
      ozstream m_zstream; ///< ozstream is a wrapper class that extends ofstream and compress data using zlib format prior to writing
};


class Storage
{
public:
    string     m_name;
    bool       m_compressed;
    int_vector m_data;
};


class StorageWriter
{
public:

    void init(string path)
    {
        m_writer.open(path)
    }

    void write(const Storage& p)
    {
        m_writer.write(p.m_name);
        m_writer.write(p.m_compressed);
        if( !p.m_compressed )
            m_writer.write(p.m_data);
        else
        {
            // TBD - how to use ZlibWriter here?
        }
    }

private:
    Writer m_writer;
};
```

***Constraints***
`StorageWriter::write()` is the bottleneck of my program. it is called countless of times and responsible for the writing of many gigabytes of data.

***Question***
I need to implement the `//TBD` section in `StorageWriter::write().`
I would like to have a simple way of "switching" between `Writer` and `ZlibWriter`.

***Suggestion 1***
Don't use `ZlibWriter`. each time I need to compress data, just compress it to temporary variable and then write it to file.
I don't like this because it will make me duplicate the whole compress mechanism already implemented in class `ZlibWriter`.

***Suggestion 2***

1. create instance of class `ZlibWriter` on the fly ( or even as a member of `StorageWriter`).
2. move position of `ZlibWriter` stream to the position class `Writer` has.
3. write data using `ZlibWriter`.
4. move position of `Writer` to the end of the file.

Not sure it is wise to have two live streams to the same file. In addition all those seek operation are not very efficient at a critical section of the program.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Maybe overload ctor or another method of ZlibWriter, such that you would be able to pass a stream into it? It won't create stream on its own then and use the one you provided on the position it currently is.

Comment: Since ZlibWriter basically extends std::ostream, is it possible to make it work with my own stream? Haven't used this partice before.

Comment: You can use rdbuf to replace the input/output buffer, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload your `ZlibWriter` ctor, such that you will be able to provide a custom stream your writer will write to. Use `std::ostream::rdbuf` to replace your output buffer with an output buffer of another stream.

Comment: Thanks. seems promising. I'll try that. But I'm still concern that once I write using ZlibWriter, the position of the file in Writer is no longer in sync with the end of the file. Need to make sure  that both streams don't overwrite the data written by the other stream.

Comment: I have to say I'm not sure, how internally streams work. But I hardly doubt that writing to another stream's buffer *won't* change it's position. That wouldn't make much sense, so I'm hopeful it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are looking for (do you always write to one file, or does every writer write to its own?) but its perfectly fine to have both writers as member variables.
you could even go as far as having a vector of Writers. so make an abstract interface that all writers include so that you can loop over the vector and simply call the write() function with your data. the writer itself will handle the writing, and thus the zlib writer will compress the data and then write it, without you having to worry about anything :)

if you need to toggle between them, you can just add a seperate member variable for your zlibwriter, and in the else case write the compressed data with the zlibwriter.

an idea to speed up the process is to share the file between writers, since only 1 process at a time will write to it, if you move the file outside the writer, and give both writers a reference to it, you can handle the seek etc from the writers, which means the next writer can just write, instead of having to do unnescessary file operations.

Comment: Always writing to the same output file. not sure I fully understand you last paragraph. If I'm working with two streams to the a single output file, I need to make sure that both streams don't overwrite the data written by the other. that's my main concern,

Comment: It was an idea to speed up the file writing, again there is not much info but for example if you have lots of small chunks and you alternate between compressed or uncompressed, you could write it to a buffer first, and flush the whole buffer to a file in 1 go. or if the order doesnt matter you could think about sorting so that you dont switch writers often